# Transpose Count From Horizontal to Vertical

Tags: t-sql

is there a way to transpose the result from horizontal to vertical in SQL Server 2008?

For example, I have this below query below.

```
Select
(Select Count(*) FROM tblJob Where JobOwnerID = e.EmployeeID) AS JobTotal,
(Select Count(*) FROM tblJob Where JobOwnerID = e.EmployeeID and Status = 'Completed') AS JobTCompleted, 
(Select Count(*) FROM tblJob Where JobOwnerID = e.EmployeeID and Status = 'Expried') AS JobExpired
FROM tblEmployee e
```

Then that query produces the result below:

```
RecID   JobTotal    JobCompleted    JobExpired
1574    167         56              167
1621    216         85              215
1676    8           2               5
```

I want to transpose from that result to vertical format as below sample.

```
RecID   Category    FieldName       Value
1574    Job         JobTotal        167
1574    Job         JobCompleted    56
1574    Job         JobExpired      167
1621    Job         JobTotal        216
1621    Job         JobCompleted    85
1621    Job         JobExpired      215
1676    Job         JobTotal        8
1676    Job         JobCompleted    2
1676    Job         JobExpired      5
```

Please advise (with sample code if possible). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find this performs better as it avoids the repeated aggregation.

```
WITH J
     AS (SELECT JobOwnerID,
                COUNT(*)   AS JobTotal,
                COUNT(CASE
                        WHEN Status = 'Completed' THEN 1
                      END) AS JobTCompleted,
                COUNT(CASE
                        WHEN Status = 'Expried' THEN 1
                      END) AS JobExpired
         FROM   tblJob
         GROUP  BY JobOwnerID)
SELECT e.RecID,
       v.FieldName,
       ISNULL(Value, 0) AS Value
FROM   tblEmployee e
       LEFT JOIN J
              ON J.JobOwnerID = E.EmployeeID
       CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ('JobTotal', JobTotal),
                            ('JobCompleted', JobTCompleted),
                            ('JobExpired', JobExpired) ) V(FieldName, Value)
```

Comment: Thank you @Martin, your solution works great (though it is complex for me. :) )

Answer (score 1):

Here is one trick using `Outer Apply`

```
SELECT RecID,
       Category,
       FieldName,
       Count(FieldName)
FROM   tblEmployee e
       Left join tblJob t on t.JobOwnerID = e.EmployeeID
       Outer apply (SELECT 'JobTCompleted' WHERE Status = 'Completed'
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'JobExpired' WHERE Status = 'JobExpired'
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'JobTotal') cs (FieldName) 
 Group By RecID,
       Category,
       FieldName
```

Comment: You need to add "FROM tblJob Where JobOwnerID = e.EmployeeID" to each of those queries inside the cross apply.

Comment: @SeanLange - Not needed. Many don't know this syntax actually exists

Comment: How could it not be needed. In the original post they need counts from tblJob, not tblEmployee

Comment: that isn't going to work as you hope. `SELECT Count(*)` without a `FROM` is going to be from a single row virtual table

Comment: This will return a cartesian from your main query and your cross apply query because that query will return three rows for every row in the rest of the query.

Comment: @MartinSmith - You are right. I just tested with sample data, didn't work as  I expected

Comment: @MartinSmith Hope it should be fine now

Comment: @SeanLange - No it is not a Cartesian product. Check it will sample data. Martin found the logical issue and I have fixed it now

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am trying now, but still having a little problem to make it work.  I think it is too complex for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot the resultant data set that you get from original query.

```
;WITH RESULT_TABLE AS
(Select e.RecID
(Select Count(*) FROM tblJob Where JobOwnerID = e.EmployeeID) AS JobTotal,
(Select Count(*) FROM tblJob Where JobOwnerID = e.EmployeeID and Status = 'Completed') AS JobTCompleted, 
(Select Count(*) FROM tblJob Where JobOwnerID = e.EmployeeID and Status = 'Expried') AS JobExpired
FROM tblEmployee e) 
SELECT RecID,[Option],[Value]
FROM
RESULT_TABLE  
UNPIVOT 
(
  [Value] FOR [Option] IN (JobTotal,JobCompleted,JobExpired)
) AS unpivotTable;
```

Comment: This is a very good solution too.  I tried and it works perfect.  Thank you very much @Amit